# How to accelerate a for loop where each iteration depends on the previous iteration

Tags: python, performance, optimization

I have Python code that I would like to make more efficient (i.e not using a for loop). Unfortunately, each iteration depends on the previous iteration in the for loop. The code looks something like this:

```
def f(x, y):
 #do something 


important_val = something
for i in range(0, large_number):
 important_val = f(i, important_val)
```

I only care about the last important_val. Is there a way to accelerate this? List comprehension and mapping are not efficient because they will store needless references to important_val.

Comment: somebody has to do the computation and it is linear so no way to speed it up but using a different language, write a C-module to be called by python, the way Numpy does it

Comment: Sometimes there are ways to divide-and-conquer the problem (e.g. partial sums, etc) but assistance with that would require us to know more about your algorithm

Comment: take a look at `numba` package. If function `f` can be represented by numba-compatible code, then the for loop around it too.

Answer (score -1):

If you only care about the final value of "important_val" use Numpy.

Here's an implementation:

```
import numpy as np

def f(x, y):
    # Your computation here
    return result

large_number = 1000  # Adjust as needed
important_val = np.zeros(1)  # Initialize as a NumPy array

for i in range(0, large_number):
    important_val[0] = f(i, important_val[0])

final_result = important_val[0]
```

Comment: This has no effect except to make everything slower. This is not how numpy can accelerate code. All you do is add two additional operations (`__getitem__` and `__setitem__`) to the loop plus conversions from and to numpy datatypes